# Parent Div Overflow Doesn't Increase Parent Size

Tags: html, css

I need code similar to this:

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
}

.static-child{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: aqua;
}

.absolute-child{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  
  background-color: red;
}

.another-container{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="static-child"></div>
  <div class="absolute-child">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-container">
<h2>
What is Lorem Ipsum?
</h2>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

</p>
</div>
```

My issue is that the parent container's overflow, caused by an absolutely positioned child ( red container ), doesn't affect the parent container's size. As a result, the content of the next div (`blue container`) goes under the absolutely positioned child div.

The content inside the absolutely positioned child is dynamic, so I can't add a fixed margin to the next div or a static child element

**How can I do this using only css ?**

**I don't want to use JavaScript for this; it should be done using only CSS. I want to emphasize that the height of the child element is variable. And I know what is absolute position I need a way to do this with or without absolute**

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/sadeq76/yr8veuf7/9/)

RESULT SHOULD BE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarifying about the `<img>`, I will update my answer.
Use `display: grid;` and specify the `grid-area` for the elements:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}

.image {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.static-child {
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}

.absolute-child {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.another-container {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/51/600/400" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="static-child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, sint, blanditiis vero voluptas nobis molestias veniam in architecto ex obcaecati.
  </div>
  <div class="absolute-child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="another-container">
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

---

Old answer with `background-color`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.static-child {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.absolute-child {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute-child:before {
  content: '';
  inset: -1000000px -1rem 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.another-container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="static-child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, sint, blanditiis vero voluptas nobis molestias veniam in architecto ex obcaecati.
  </div>
  <div class="absolute-child">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
<div class="another-container">
  <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but I want to replace the static container with an image. However, I can't do this with the current code because the 'aqua' colored container is split into two parts: 'absolute-child::before' and the static child.

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace the image with? All background aqua?

Comment: The aqua-colored part on my website is not a `div`; it is an `img`. so i can't use your code

Comment: It would be nice to add these explanations to your question. Because now there is no mention of the `img`...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is how absolute position works. It's out of, let's say, the "flow" of nodes. You can try a simple workaround like this:

```
.parent {
        position: relative;
    }
    .static-child {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: aqua;
    }
    .absolute-child {
        /* bottom: 0; */
        /* position:absolute; */
        margin-left: 1rem; /* added this */
        margin-right: 1rem; /* added this */
        transform: translateY(-50%); /* changed this */
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, my friend. Thank you for your response. However, in my scenario, 50% of the `absolute-child` elements should be positioned beneath the static child. Unfortunately, your code does not achieve this. I have simplified my code.

Comment: You want to have the red block underneath the aqua block so that only 50% of the red block is visible? Then add to .static child `position:relative; z-index:10;`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Absolute positioning takes an element out of normal document flow.

You can check out this tutorial for getting good understanding of position property :[Tutorial Link](https://youtu.be/jx5jmI0UlXU?si=fqbFxufjuj6Limk4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on it, but I've found another solution with one drawback

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.static-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: aqua;
}

.spacer {
  height: 145px;
}

.content-child{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-inline: 1rem;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.another-container{
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="static-child"></div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="content-child">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-container">
  <h2>  What is Lorem Ipsum? </h2>
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

In this code, I added another container as a spacer and set the 'aqua' container as the absolute container because I know the height of the 'aqua' container. I can set the spacer's height, and as a result, the 'red' container moves downward.

**The drawback is that I can't be certain that 50 percent of the red container overlaps with the aqua container**